# Redirect only certain paths

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect only some pages to make the URL neater, such as:

Original : http://www.mywebsite.com/form.php

What I want : http://www.mywebsite.com/form AND http://www.mywebsite.com/form/

How do I write the htaccess file for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested but something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^form.php(/)?$  http://www.mywebsite.com/form$1 [L]
```